# Rename columns with special signs and numbers

Tags: python, pandas, replace, rename

I have this

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'st': {0: '0', 1: '>0-<10', 2: '>=10-<20', 3: '>=20'}} )
```

which yields

```
       st
    0
    >0-<10
    >=10-<20
    >=20
```

Each entry of [st] column represents a category.

I would like to replace categories as follows:

```
   st
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

to achieve this, I tried:

```
dic = {
'0':'1',
'>0-<10':'2',        
'>=10-<20':'3', 
'>=20':'4'}

df['st'] = df['st'].replace(dic, regex=True)
```

I also tried

```
conditions =["0",
    ">0-<10",
    ">=10-<20",
    ">=20"]

choices =["1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"]

df["st2"]=np.select(conditions,choices)
```

Unfortunately, neither of these code solutions yield to desired output.

Comment: Try looking at [Pandas - Rename Categories in Category Column](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-rename-categories-in-category-column/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the column to `category` dtype and get codes with `cat.codes`. This will number the categories starting from 0, so you may also add 1:

```
df['st'] = df['st'].astype('category').cat.codes + 1
```

Comment: excellent, then how do I rename them back to original values?

Comment: @josepmaria change `df['st'] =` to `df['st2'] = `